# how to change value of submit button of comment form?

Tags: forms

I wanted to change the default value of submit button in comment form from "Save" to "Post". I wanted to do that using a module , not javascript. So I wrote the following code in my module.

```
 function mymodule_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){

     $form['actions']['submit'] = array(

      '#value' => t('Post Comments'),   
     );
     }
```

But instead of changing the value of submit button, this module is making the submit button hidden. If I add `return $form`  , then the submit button displays but with the same default text "Save". Any suggestions please. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're replacing the entire element at the moment (which is why it doesn't show). You can change a specific property in the array like so:

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t('Post Comments');
```

That way you're just setting the `#value` property, and not removing the other properties that already exist for the element.

Comment: Yes. That was the mistake I was doing.It works now. Thank you for your quick response Clive.